# How to split list of integers in SQL Server, passed as a string(eg:1,2,3,4,5) from front end to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to pass a list of integers as String from front end to a SQL Server database, e.g. : (2,3,4,5)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetMultipleCustomerByID
    @Id nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Firstname, Lastname 
    FROM
        Customer 
    WHERE
        CustomerID IN (@Id)
END

Exec GetMultipleCustomerByID "2,3,4,5"
```

Above represented values (2,3,4,5) are ID values (primary key) of the table.

From these id, I have to retrieve the rows from the table.

The string "2,3,4,5" may be dynamic. May include more than or less than 4 numbers.

Comment: it's a string, so you'd need string operations to slice things apart on the `,`, which means you need a loop to do this iteratively. That or you use dynamic sql, and build a new query statement, interpolating your string into the new query. e.g `@sql = 'SELECT ...  in (' + @id + ')'; exec @sql;`-type stuff.

Comment: i dont know how to iterate, Can you please give the Solution ..

Comment: he already give you the solution, use a `dynamic sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but one simple way is dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetMultipleCustomerByID (
    @Ids nvarchar(50)
) as
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    set @sql = 'select Firstname, Lastname from Customer where CustomerID in (@Ids)';
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@Ids', @Ids);

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
END;

Exec GetMultipleCustomerByID "2,3,4,5";
```